# Why is there no Carousel in @assistant/conversation

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

If not, I want to use more than two cards. If not, I want to know how to use List (list code example).

Absolutely not Dialogflow code! I need the ActionsOnGoogle code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const syncRequest = require('sync-request');
const express = require('express');
const {
  conversation,
  Simple,
  Card,
  Image,
  Button,
  List,
  Table,
  Carousel <-------------------------------(Carousel is not constructor ERROR) 
}  = require('@assistant/conversation');

const app = conversation({debug:true});

app.handle('callApi', (conv) => {
     conv.add(new Card({
          title: "hello1",
          subtitle:  "hi",
           text: "blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla",
            image: new Image({
              url: "some url",
              alt: "Some alternative text",
            })
        }), new Card({
          title: "hello2",
          subtitle:  "ddddddddd",
           text: "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest",
            image: new Image({
              url: "some url",
              alt: "Some alternative text",
            })
        }));----------------------------------------------------two Card doesn't it work
});

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Looking for ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment document and example/sample code link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Carousel type has been replaced by the [Collection](https://actions-on-google.github.io/assistant-conversation-nodejs/3.1.0/interfaces/_api_schema_.collection.html) type, which does the same thing on most platforms. The name reflects, however, that it may not display as a carousel everywhere, but will still represent a card-like layout.

For Visual Selection Responses such as Lists and Collections, defining the response is done in two parts:

1. Creating [Runtime Type Overrides](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/types#runtime_type_overrides) for a type, and including visual information about each entry
2. Creating the List or Collection and referencing items in that type to display

You'll create [Type Overrides](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=builder#node.js_5) by adding something to the session. So it might look something like this:

```
  conv.session.typeOverrides = [{
    name: 'prompt_option',
    mode: 'TYPE_REPLACE',
    synonym: {
      entries: [
        {
          name: 'ITEM_1',
          synonyms: ['Item 1', 'First item'],
          display: {
             title: 'Item #1',
             description: 'Description of Item #1',
             image: ASSISTANT_LOGO_IMAGE,
                }
        },
        {
          name: 'ITEM_2',
          synonyms: ['Item 2', 'Second item'],
          display: {
             title: 'Item #2',
             description: 'Description of Item #2',
             image: ASSISTANT_LOGO_IMAGE,
                }
        },
        {
          name: 'ITEM_3',
          synonyms: ['Item 3', 'Third item'],
          display: {
             title: 'Item #3',
             description: 'Description of Item #3',
             image: ASSISTANT_LOGO_IMAGE,
                }
        },
        {
          name: 'ITEM_4',
          synonyms: ['Item 4', 'Fourth item'],
          display: {
             title: 'Item #4',
             description: 'Description of Item #4',
             image: ASSISTANT_LOGO_IMAGE,
                }
        },
        ]
    }
  }];
```

You would then create and add the Collection object, referencing the keys from the type you are declaring:

```
  conv.add(new Collection({
    title: 'Collection Title',
    subtitle: 'Collection subtitle',
    items: [
      {
        key: 'ITEM_1'
      },
      {
        key: 'ITEM_2'
      },
      {
        key: 'ITEM_3'
      },
      {
        key: 'ITEM_4'
      }
    ],
  }));
});
```

doing this for a List instead would be similar. The entity type and visual components would be the same, but you'd define the list slightly differently:

```
  conv.add(new List({
    title: 'List title',
    subtitle: 'List subtitle',
    items: [
      {
        key: 'ITEM_1'
      },
      {
        key: 'ITEM_2'
      },
      {
        key: 'ITEM_3'
      },
      {
        key: 'ITEM_4'
      }
    ],
  }));
});
```